# How to move a manged package from one dev org to dev another?

Tags: managed-package, environment-hub

The context is We just got signed up as an ISV. we had a managed package built by a contractor in his dev org. I want to move the code base into our proper dev org . Please note I am not looking to deploy the application. I need to make changes etc. to the code and get it ready for beta

Comment: You will want to look for the "Force.com Migration Tool" (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to move code from one org to another is to use ant. This allows you to deploy the metadata from your developer I to to your ISV org.

Comment: You might want to mention that it's easier to use ant if you create a package in the source org first, because you're less likely to miss dependencies.